# Sum of Pascal's triangle column

Tags: combinatorics

$$\sum^n_{i=1} \frac{(-1)^i}{i}{n\choose i} = 2$$
How exactly should I show that this stands? Can somebody help me with the proof?

Comment: It is clearly is not true for $n=1$ or the next few values of $n$

Comment: Where did this question come from?

Comment: The left hand side is in fact $-\displaystyle\sum^n_{i=1} \frac{1}{i}$, the negative of the harmonic numbers

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Please, consider updating your question to include what you have tried and where you are getting stuck. That way, people on this site will know exactly what help you need.

Answer (score 2):

Define $f(x):=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{(-1)^i}ix^i\binom ni$. Then for $x\neq 0$,  $$f'(x)=\sum_{i=1}^nx^{i-1}(-1)^i\binom ni=\frac{(1-x)^n-1}x=-\frac xx\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}(1-x)^j=-\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}(1-x)^j,$$
hence 
$$f(x)-f(1)=-\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\int_1^x(1-t)^n\mathrm dt=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\int_0^{1-x}s^n\mathrm ds.$$
We have $f(0)=0$, hence $f(1)=-\sum_{j=1}^n\frac 1j$.