# Formula for sum of combinations

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, summation, permutations, combinations

I am trying to find a closed-form formula or, at least, a different and more useful representation for the following sum of combinations:

\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{n!}{i!(n-i)!}\times\frac{(-1)^i}{i}
\end{equation}

Comment: I believe it is $$\sum_{i=1}^n-\dfrac{1}{i} = -H_n$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have that

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{n!}{i!(n-i)!}\times\frac{(-1)^i}{i}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{(-1)^i}{i}\binom{n}{i}$$

then refer to

- [Sum of Pascal's triangle column](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/572431/505767)
- [Let $n$ be a positive integer, Prove that $\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{ (-1)^{k-1}}{k}{n \choose k} = H_n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2581697/505767)

Comment: Thank you, that's what I was looking for!

Comment: @Andrei You are welcome! Bye

Answer (score 3):

Hint : sub this into the sum
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{1}{i}=\int_0^1 x^{i-1} dx.
\end{eqnarray*}
Now invert the order of the integral and the plum. Use the binomial theorem, do the obvious substitution, expand and integrate to get the result stated by Interstellar Probe.

Answer (score 3):

Starting from 
$$(1-x)^n = 1 +\color{blue}{x}\sum_{i=\color{blue}{1}}^n\binom ni (-1)^ix^{\color{blue}{i-1}} \Leftrightarrow \frac{(1-x)^n-1}{x} = \sum_{i=1}^n\binom ni (-1)^ix^{i-1}$$

you get

$$\Rightarrow \frac{(1-x)^n-1}{x} = -\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(1-x)^i = \sum_{i=1}^n\binom ni (-1)^ix^{i-1}$$

Now, integrate

$$ -\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\int_0^1(1-x)^i dx = \sum_{i=1}^n\binom ni (-1)^i \int_0^1x^{i-1}dx$$

Hence,
$$-\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{i+1}  = -H_n = \sum_{i=1}^n\binom ni \frac{(-1)^i}{i} $$